# The required version of WcfDataServices is missing

Tags: rest, apple-ios

I try to add a list item via the SharePoint 2013 REST API (in Objective C) and keep getting the following error:

```
{
"error":{
"code":"-1, System.InvalidOperationException",
"message":{
"lang":"en-US",
"value":"The required version of WcfDataServices is missing. Please refer to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=321931 for more information."
}}}
```

Authentication works just fine, I am also able to retrieve lists.

I access the following url:

```
<sharepointurl>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(%27Announcements%27)/items
```

and provide the following data:

Header:

```
X-RequestDigest
Accept
```

Data:

```
{
'_metadata':{'type':'SP.AnnouncementsListItem},
'Title':'Posting to Sharepoint API'
}
```

Http-Method:

```
POST
```

Unfortunately I cannot find any information when googling the error I am receiving.

Has anyone faced this error and can help me?

Thanks & kind regards.

Answer (score 5):

Please see link below. The fix for me was to add header “Content-Type” = “application/json;odata=verbose”

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25415427/create-a-folder-in-sp2013-using-rest-and-httpclient

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this simply by `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` to my header.
Unfortunately it does not appear in microsoft's documentation here `https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest` and it cost me a lot of time.

I found it by tracing my older projects that used AJAX to communicate with SharePoint 2013 on-prem.

---

```
{
   "Accept":"application/json; odata=verbose",
   "Content-Type":"application/json; odata=verbose",
   "X-RequestDigest": "`[FORM DIGEST]`",
   "IF-MATCH":"*",
   "X-HTTP-Method":" DELETE",
   "X-Requested-With":"XMLHttpRequest"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I tried on another freshly installed SharePoint and it works without issues.

Possibly some configuration problem.